# A homogeneous subset of ℕ is one where all the elements have the same parity. Prove that the set all homogeneous subsets of ℕ is uncountable.

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

**Question**

A homogeneous subset of ℕ is one where all the elements have the same parity. A student decided to prove that the set all homogeneous subsets of ℕ is uncountable. The student proposed that every homogeneous subset of N can be represented as an infinite binary word with all its 1s either in even positions or in odd positions. For instance, {1, 3, 5, 7, 9 . . .} can be represented by the infinite binary word 1010101010......, and {2,4,10} by 0101000001000..., and ∅ = { } by 000..., and so on.

With B being the set of all infinite binary words satisfying the above condition, the student mimicked Cantor’s diagonalization proof in order to construct a infinite binary word w such that there is no i ∈ ℕ with f(i) = w. He did this by flipping bits along the diagonal (as shown below).

[image: Image of table]

(a) What’s wrong with the student’s proof?

(b) Fix the student’s proof.

**What I did**

For a) I said that the student's proof is flawed because it assumes that the set of all subsets of ℕ can be put into one-to-one correspondence  with the set of all infinite binary words. However it can't be put into this correspondence because not every infinite binary word corresponds to a unique homogenous subset of ℕ.

For b) I was confused on how to fix the students proof. I was thinking of showing that mapping diagonally the set of infinite binary words with a subset of ℕ, but I'm not sure how to approach this to prove that the subsets of ℕ is uncountable in this case.

Comment: The simplest proof would be an injective map from the parts of $\mathbb{N}$ to homogeneous subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ which is $S \mapsto 2 \cdot S$.

Comment: Think about the number of digit of $w$ in student's proof. Is it too long for being a natural number?